# WinCE 5.0 "SRAM Depletion on continual running of application"

Tags: windows, registry, windows-ce

Please help with the following scenario in a WinCE 5.0 device

1. I am using registry dword's to store some 30 values.
2. These registry values are getting updated every minute (no new key creation, its just updation).
3. Now I use the following API to get the bytes available

   ```
   public static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName,

   out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable,

   out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes,

   out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
   ```
4. The findings are that after doing the keys updation for around 77K times, I lose some 23 KB of memory (total number of free bytes is 23 KB less).

Even after restarting the device, I am seeing that those 23 KB are not retained (They are lost).

Please help with the following questions

=> What is the reason of depleted SRAM

=> How to reclaim this lost memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have a Hive-based registry and the OS is storing the deltas from the base startup registry.  Does it stay steady at 23k?  Does 23k really matter? If you're not leaking memory over time, then what's the worry?